# FX quoting convention

Tags: fx, fxo

I saw the quote as this: EUR/USD 1m ATM 0.3150/0.3190. I guess these are vol levels. What the units of these bid and offer quoted?

Answer (score 2):

Fx volatility quote conventions are typically esoteric and befuddling. For example, EUR/USD 1m ATM would be the volatility at the strike of a zero spot delta (without premium) straddle. The quote is in percentage, as is typical for vol so read that as 0.315% / 0.319% annualized volatility.

Comment: Should be 31.5% and 31.9% annualised volatility